# Xamarin 5.x translation projects not supported?

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin, translation

I updated my xamarin studio to version 5.1.2 and now get the error that translation projects are not supported, when loading my project. Has xamarin dropped translation projects, or how are they handled now? I use Mono for running the project on Linux. I haven't found a bug on bugzilla.xamarin.com, but I can't be the only one, that uses translation projects?!

Thanks for any information you provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to open the Addin Manager and enable the `IDE extensions / Gettext Translations Support`

Hope that helps.